# Q:How to if contidion from json on React in one component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to make the type of product to add and hide things, can I use only one component because I do it right now with two. I have an if that renders ProductNew and ProductOld. Is it possible to make the differences in one compartment or not?

This is the json:

```
{
"products": {
    "product": {
        "type": "new",
        "new": {
            "text": "Some text..."
        },
        "attr": {
            "price": "20"
        }
    },
    "product2": {
        "type": "old",
        "attr": {
            "price": "10"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, yes. Just pass the type as a property into your single component and then move the if statements into that.

So the calling code would look like

```
<YourComponent type="{this.props.type}" />
```

and the component would have, for example

```
<div>
{this.props.type == "New" ?
    <span>New Stuff</span> :
    <span>Old Stuff</span>
}
</div>
```

if you don't want anything in the old then just use

```
<div>
{this.props.type == "New" ?
    <span>New Stuff</span> :
    null
}
</div>
```